# fopen in NASM returns zero in rax

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am using fopen to open a file in NASM.  In the .rodata section I declare the file name and file mode:

```
qsort_filename: db "/opt/P01_SH/_Test_Data/Random_int64_t.bin",0x0
qsort_filemode:  db "r",0x0
```

To open the file in the .text section:

```
mov rdi,qsort_filename
mov rsi,qsort_filemode
call [rel fopen wrt ..got]
```

but it returns zero in rax.  No error is reported.  The file name is correct.

Comment: Mode may need to be zero-terminated too.

Comment: I did that, but still zero in rax.

Comment: Run `strace ./a.out` to see what error the underlying `open` syscall got.  I'm surprised no errors were reported; `errno` should be set to an error code when `fopen` returns NULL, as documented in the man page.  (Running the whole program under `strace` to decode the params and error-return numbers for you is easier, and a good first step.  If it's `-ENOENT` or `-EPERM`, then you know right away to check on the file, like try `ls -l` or `cat` on it with the same path.)

Comment: Is errno returned in a register?

Comment: I'm not familiar with using strace in assembly, so I'm working on that now.

Comment: Strace is easy.  I run from a shell script with ./script.sh, just run strace ./script.sh.  Strace reported no errors.  But It turns out my problem was more fundamental -- gdb was directed to the wrong source version, so its output did not match the correct output.  Now I have a handle in rax.  Sometimes the problems are so simple.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: `errno` is a global variable, separate from the return value.  Remember these are C functions.  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html.  (There might be some trickery like thread-local storage for `errno` in modern ABIs, so look at C compiler output for a function like `int foo(){ return errno;}` or look at it in a debugger.

Comment: If you're not running your assembly program directly, `strace -f ./script.sh` to follow forks, otherwise you're just tracing `bash` or `/bin/sh` while it forks and waits for the child process that execs your program.  Or put `strace` into your run script, or just run your asm program manually instead of via the script once.